# Android listview onContextMenu listener not working

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, long-press

I've tried almost everything available on SO and related sites.

1. Checked this approach (and failed) : Override two activity methods and register the listview object for context menu.
2. OnLongItemClick : Even this one didn't work. I've simply added logs to see if control is coming inside listview and it doesn't come.

Additional information : I've a custom listview and custom adapter for the same. To avoid dispatchDraw crashes, the listview looks like this

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView {

public CustomListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    try {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        // need not catch
    }
  }
}
```

Right now code is like this

```
listView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() { ..... }

registerForContextMenu(listView);
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {}/*Activity method overriden*/
```

Any clues ? Already spent an hour trying different things but nothing worked

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu